# dynamically show and hide link when switch button is checked/unchecked using jquery codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have created a category module and switch button on then link show and switch button off then link hide. I am using codeigniter framemwork.

**controller:**

```
class Category extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('category_model');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

 public function index() {
        if (!empty($_SESSION['admin'])) {
            $data = array(
                'page_title' => 'Category',
                'page_name' => 'category/index',
                'result' => $this->category_model->list_all()
            );
            $this->load->view('template', $data);
        } else {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }

 public function update_cat_status() {
        $data = $this->category_model->update_cat_status($_GET);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

**VIew:**

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Category Name</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Edit</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php foreach ($result as $value): ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?= $value['name']; ?></td>
                                        <td> <div class="onoffswitch">
                                                <input type="hidden" value="<?= $value["id"]; ?>"/>
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch"
                                                <?php
                                                if ($value['status'] == 1) {
                                                    echo "checked";
                                                }
                                                ?>>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><a href="<?= base_url("category/edit/{$value['id']}"); ?>" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //category switch
    $('.onoffswitch').change(function () {
        var cat_id = $(this).children(':hidden').val();
        if ($(this).children(':checked').length === 0)
        {
            var status = 0;

        }
        else
        {
            var status = 1;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: base_url + "category/update_cat_status",
            data: {status: status, cat_id: cat_id},
            success: function (response) {
                //console.log(response);

            }
        });

    });
});
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDJtS.jpg)

MY Question:
switch button on then edit button hide and switch button off then edit buttton show.
so please view above screenshot

Comment: @Tanmay please help me..

Comment: $(this).children(':checked').length u don't need to do this thing you just put if($(this).children(':checked')){status=1;)else{status=0}; and put var status outside the if condition var status=0 or status=1  depend on default value

Comment: @Tanmay please write you code

Comment: @Tanmay i don't understand,so please write you code

Comment: I never work in codeigniter before I am just suggesting you with jquery

Comment: @Tanmay but my question: switch button on then edit button hide and switch button off then edit buttton show. so please view above screenshot

Comment: Yes I got it but I neef code or fiddle 4 it I dont knw codeigniter so I need html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add id attribute to your button in view:

from `<a href="<?= base_url("category/edit/{$value['id']}"); ?>" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>`

to: `<a id="btnEdit<?= $value['id']?>" href="<?= base_url("category/edit/{$value['id']}"); ?>" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>`

2. on your jquery:

> if ($(this).children(':checked'))
>
> ```
> {
>  var status = 1;
>  $("#btnEdit"+cat_id).show();
> }
> else
> {
>  var status = 0;
>  $("#btnEdit"+cat_id).hide();
> }
> ```

Comment: your code is not work, means i checked button then edit button show and, unchcked button then edit button show ,

Comment: @omer Cabrera MY Question: i checked button then edit button show and unchecked button then edit button hide

Comment: i checked button then edit button hide but page refresh then edit button show, why,please help me.